# How to solve the invalid projection error in CRS?

Tags: runtime-error, geopandas, pyproj

```
from pyproj import CRS
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

import json
import pandas as pd

gdf = geopandas.read_file("Frog_Census_Records.geojson")
```

The error displayed is :

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: no database context specified)
```

Could someone kindly help me ?

Comment: How did you install pyproj? What is the output of `python -m pyproj -v`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When displaying errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - they're critical to understanding the full source of the error. Thanks! And yes, this is likely an installation/environment setup issue, so more info about how you set up your python environment and how you installed geopandas, proj, and fiona would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- assuming that your data set is this: https://data.gov.au/dataset/ds-vic-d328facd-7545-4d30-aa4e-a5c617b748c0/details?q=
- it is in EPSG:4326 so does not need to be projected.  Both **plotly express** and **geopandas** plotting works without projections

```
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import plotly.express as px

# gdf = gpd.read_file("Frog_Census_Records.geojson")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(requests.get("https://data-melbournewater.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/07e011c3e36f4b0aa8023d096d5a50a8_0.geojson?outSR=%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A28355%2C%22wkid%22%3A28355%7D").json())

# px.scatter_mapbox(gdf, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", color="Common_name").update_layout(mapbox={"style":"carto-positron"})
gdf.plot(column="Common_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because geopandas was installed by conda but other packages like pyproj was installed by pip.

I installed everything with pip and it solved the problem.

```
pip install geopandas
```

Reference: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1887